# Get value from the console during code execution in selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to `Debug.Print` a value in the immediate window of an input text field 
so when found that this line can be executed in the console

```
document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value
```

I thought it may be useful for me if I could get that value into the immediate window
I have tried such line but returned nothing in the immediate window (no error occurred but nothing in the immediate window)

```
Debug.Print .ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#txtCaptcha').value;")
```

Simply I am searching for a way to be able to get the value from javascript command. I have no idea about javascript so I am stuck

Comment: Do you have any text field defined in your page with id `txtCaptcha` ?

Comment: Yes there is a field with this id `txtCaptcha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing HTMLDocument and Selenium examples in the above.

You cannot return text in either scenario from `ExecuteScript` (or `execScript` for IE) direct. Use your script to write the value to an existing node (or create a new one) and then read from that via DOM parser.

```
Dim s As String
s = "captcha = document.querySelector('#txtCaptcha').value;" & _
    "document.title = captcha;"

.ExecuteScript s
.FindElementByTag("Title").Text
```

But if `FindElementById("txtCaptcha").Attribute("value")` doesn't return the value I would be surprised if using javascript will. Though testing with javascript in browser using url from a prior question of yours does return the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for great efforts. I encountered error at the last line so I changed to `Debug.Print .FindElementByTag("Title").Text` > but I got empty in the immediate window.

Comment: I am not surprised. But the process in general above is correct for how to return from ExecuteScript.

Comment: Side note: Have you checked btw your element is not inside an iframe? Because from your prior url it is.

Comment: Yes in the code I recognize it is in frame so I used `.SwitchToFrame "searchCaseDiv"`

Comment: Use the iframe url direct. It works with IE https://pastebin.com/DkaT1LJr

Comment: How can I use the frame direct? I didn't get what you mean

Comment: .get the url in my pastebin. It is the src of the iframe

Comment: That's great. It is working on IE. So why doesn't it work on chrome when using selenium?! And how this can be accessed in chrome using selenium as the original code in selenium VBA as you know

Comment: I can only test selenium in other languages at present. No longer with VBA. I can re-write IE to selenium for you to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196619/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).

Answer (score 1):

Just add return in front of your JS script.

```
Debug.Print .ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('#txtCaptcha').value;")
```